# AJAX PHP - Receive Get Several Variable Data

Tags: php, ajax, get

I have a php file which has some variables like $name1, $name2...
How can i receive those values in my check loop page with AJAX ?

**Main loop page.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkdata ( )
{
  ....?
}
  setTimeout ( "checkdata()", 3000 );
</script>
```

**PHP file (info.php)**

```
<?php
$name1=7;
$name2=3;
.
.
.
?>
```

Comment: Don't: `setTimeout ("checkdata()", 3000);`. Do: `setTimeout(checkdata, 3000);`.

Comment: You need to output them in the page returned to the AJAX call; then make sure the AJAX call knows how to handle the output you send.

Comment: _Don't: setTimeout ("checkdata()", 3000);. Do: setTimeout(checkdata, 3000);_ hmn, it works in both way, what's the difference? :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP

```
$info['name1'] = 7;
$info['name2'] = 3;
echo json_encode($info);
```

JS

```
function checkData()
{
    $.ajax({
       url: "info.php",
       dataType: "JSON",
       success: function(info){
           alert(info.name1);
           alert(info.name2);
       }
    });
}
```